# AlertDialog doesn't close

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-alertdialog

I have an AlertDialog where positiveButton click should perform sharedPreferences string set changes, however, there is an issue with dialog not being closed after pressing positiveButton. What's more, after every click on the button it creates one more dialog so they accumulate...

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
            builder.setTitle(android.R.string.dialog_alert_title);
            builder.setMessage("...");
            builder.setCancelable(false);
            builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Set<String> myNewSet = individualScheduleDays;//Default shared preference string set
                    myNewSet.remove(Integer.toString(scheduleID));
                    editor.remove(DAYS_WITH_INDIVIDUAL_SCHEDULE);
                    editor.commit();
                    editor.putStringSet(DAYS_WITH_INDIVIDUAL_SCHEDULE, myNewSet);
                    editor.commit();

                }
            });
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();
```

I found out that if I call editor.commit() only ones, everything is okay with dialog, but `sharedPreference` isn't changed.

Comment: try editor.apply() instead

Answer (score 3):

Dialogs don't dismiss by themselves.

Try this:

```
//editor.remove(DAYS_WITH_INDIVIDUAL_SCHEDULE); // not needed
//editor.commit();     // not needed
editor.putStringSet(DAYS_WITH_INDIVIDUAL_SCHEDULE, myNewSet);
editor.commit();
dialog.dismiss();
```

Comment: I've tried that before. Dialog closes fine, but sharedPreferences doesn't changed.

Comment: SharedPrefs are rock solid, the error must be in your logic somewhere. Post more code for further help.

Answer (score 1):

Inside the onClick function of positiveButton you have to use

```
editor.dismiss();
```